# Is spliceosomal RNA called snRNP or snRNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, terminology, rna, noncoding-rna

I have been reading articles by various sources, and they seem to interchangeably call the U1/U2/U4/U6 compounds involved in RNA splicing snRNPs as well as snRNAs.

This confuses me deeply. They must only be one or the other, no?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Another post with no reference supporting your assertion and no evidence of an attempt to solve a trivial question of nomenclature that an internet search would have answered. Please discontinue this practice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivial question about nomenclature that is easily solved by an internet search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**snRNA**: small nuclear ribonucleic acid

**snRNP**: small nuclear ribonucleoprotein

snRNA refers to the RNA itself. snRNP refers to snRNA complexed with some protein(s). You could call spliceosomal RNA either depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Most small and large RNAs typically exist and function in complex with proteins as ribonucleoprotein particles so the second denomination is more appropriate.